# How to design an app to keep a set of strings across models in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, model-view-controller

I'm writing an app that connects to the network through a server and client (stored as two strings). My app consists of multiple view controllers and models (maybe 10 of each...at least); however, almost every one of my models is going to need access to these strings (plus maybe another two or three).  What is the best way to have these strings persist across models?  The models themselves are very different except for these strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're making a mistake by spreading your networking code throughout your entire application.  The interface to the server is a single responsibility that should be factored out into its own class.  Your models then talk to this class without having to know any of the details about *how* that class talks to the server.  The simplest approach I've found for that is a faux singleton.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings don't change, you could use preprocessor macros:

```
#define kNetwork @"myNetwork"
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be several possible ways, some of which are -

1. You can use `NSUserDefaults` to save these string values and use when you need.
2. You can store these strings in `plist` files.
3. You can create a model class consisting these two string values, and create a `singleton` instance of that.
4. You can create a constant class and have these string values as a constant.

etc.